# Onclick="should javascript go here?"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to list some students in a loop in PHP with ajax. And i am going to use the return data to show in a div. But also every student should have a link for editing, and it should be done in ajax too. If anyone has a better idea, i really need to listen, but this is as far as i can get. And also there is another problem.
If i write the php like this,

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="function(){$.ajax({ type: "GET",url: "/actions/liststudents.php\",success: function(html)\{$(\"#liststudents\").html(html);}});}\" >Edit</a> - '.$id.' - '.$name.' '.$surname.'<br />';
```

I get the html as this,

```
<a href="#" onclick="function(){$.ajax({ type: " get",url:="" "="" actions="" liststudents.php\",success:="" function(html)\{$(\"#liststudents\").html(html);}});}\"="">Edit</a>
 - 3 - name surname
<br>
```

But there is another problem with my javascript that i get a solid syntax error.

If there is any better way of achieving the same effect, i really need it, because this is not looking good.
If there is no other way, if you can help me, ill be very glad
Thank you guys

Comment: Sorry, but you are including `"` in between your `onclick` in your HTML element, which is wrong. Try adding, `'` this instead of `"` in your `function()` code.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are trying to accomplish, why does each student's edit button reload the list of students?

Comment: after you fix your double quotes error, you might want to give a unique id to each of your anchor tags "id-1" "id-2" "id-3" ... this is possible through the loop. in this case you can write one javascript method to handle all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just give you  a class such as "edit" and the target the class within a separate js file:

For instance:

```
<a href="#" class="edit">Edit</edit>
```

And in the js file

```
$(".edit").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "your url here",
    success: function(){
     //Whatever you need to do
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put an id on your `<a id="someid"></a>`

after use:

```
$(function() {
  $("#someid").click(function() {
     // put your code here
  })
})
```

Comment: If there are multiple students displayed the a class would be more appropriate than an id.

Answer (score 0):

You could select the element by id or class name and then bind a click event to the element.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    // ..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you must call function, not define it. like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunc();">blablabla</a>
<script>
function myFunc(){
  alert('test');
}
</script>
```